Adapting MassTransit to existing Azure ServiceBus Topology
Currently I am investigating if and how we can use MassTransit to replace NServiceBus. Aside from the wire compatibility (the serialization of the messages and headers), which seems doable, I am struggeling a bit with the topology (the setup of queues and topics).
For example, I have an Orders queue, which receives all kind of Order related commands, i.e. CreateOrder, CancelOrder. When I try to configure MassTransit, I am able to get an Orders queue created using
builder.Services.AddMassTransit(mt => {
  mt.AddConsumer<CreateOrderConsumer>();

  mt.UsingAzureServiceBus((context, cfg) => {
    cfg.Host("conn-string");

    cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("Orders", e => {
      e.ConfigureConsumers(context);
    });

  });
});

However, this also creates a Topic CreateOrder, with a single subscription "Orders" which will forward all messages to the "Orders" queue. Although this will work, having a topic for this is a change in the existing topology, and having a topic for a many-to-one communication (like sending a command instead of publishing an event) seems odd to me.
How can I configure MassTransit to only create the Orders queue, without the CreateOrder topic, and configure sending components using MassTransit to send to this queue directly (instead of sending it to the topic)?

e.ConfigureConsumeTopology = false
Documentation

Thanks for pointing in the right direction. I tried several things.
Specifying ConfigureConsumeTopology = false on the whole receive endpoint also didn't create additional event subscriptions.
Configuring the AddConsumer with .Endpoint(e=> e.ConfigureConsumeTopology = false ); didnt seem to have any effect at all. Is that expected?
What finally did the trick is use e.ConfigureMessageTopology(typeof(PlaceOrderCommand), false); on the receive endpoint.

I suspect specifying this on the entire endpoint wouldn't work because it needs to be per message, as commands could go straight to the queue, but events need to be fanned out and require a topic. And since MT doesn't have a message type identification by default (at least I'm not aware of anything like that), it's on the API user to determine how to route messages.  I will say that the API name is confusing and lacking XML documentation, making it almost undiscoverable.

With the help of Chris his answer, I came to the following solution:

Specifying e.ConfigureMessageTopology = false; on the receive endpoint disabled all topology creation, also for other event subscriptions:

builder.Services.AddMassTransit(mt => {
  mt.AddConsumer<CreateOrderConsumer>();

  mt.UsingAzureServiceBus((context, cfg) => {
    cfg.Host("conn-string");

    cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("Orders", e => {
      // This disabled all topology creation
      e.ConfigureMessageTopology = false;
      e.ConfigureConsumers(context);
    });
  });
});


Configuring the Endpoint on AddConsumer didn't seem to have any effect at all. This would be the cleanest solution I guess, since that would disable the topic creation regardless of the receive endpoints configured. Not sure if I'm doing something wrong, or that this is expected behavior?

builder.Services.AddMassTransit(mt => {
  mt.AddConsumer<CreateOrderConsumer>().Endpoint(e =>
  {
    // This doesn't seem to have any effect?
    e.ConfigureConsumeTopology = false;
  });

  mt.UsingAzureServiceBus((context, cfg) => {
    cfg.Host("conn-string");

    cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("Orders", e => {
      e.ConfigureConsumers(context);
    });
  });
});


Adding the [ConfigureConsumeTopology(false)] attribute on the Command definition did work, however, I don't want to bloat the messages with these kind of attributes.
Specifying e.ConfigureMessageTopology(typeof(CreateOrderCommand), false); is what finally had the best outcome: no topic being created for PlaceOrderCommand, while still event subscriptions being created for other messages.

builder.Services.AddMassTransit(mt => {
  mt.AddConsumer<CreateOrderConsumer>();

  mt.UsingAzureServiceBus((context, cfg) => {
    cfg.Host("conn-string");

    cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("Orders", e => {
      // This did the trick
      e.ConfigureMessageTopology(typeof(CreateOrderCommand), false);
      e.ConfigureConsumers(context);
    });
  });
});

